# Jasper_Report_Module compatible with Odoo 8?

Tags: ubuntu, module, odoo

I tried to install jasper report on my Odoo server (Version 8.0rc1) but got an error like this:

```
OpenERP server error
ImportError No module named osv
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to all python files in jasper module and where is :

from osv import ...

replace to :

from openerp.osv import ....

Hope it helps!